# bash doesn't think lxc is installed, apt thinks it is

Tags: command-line, apt, lxc

This screenshot sums up my problem:

[image: Beautiful screenshot]

I've run `apt-get update`, `upgrade`, `purge`, `autoremove` and then `install` again. No luck. Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You should report this as a bug.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug; trying to run the non existent command `lxc` should not suggest installing the lxc package since no such command exists.

Comment: Works okay in 12.04....'The following NEW packages will be installed: `bridge-utils cgroup-lite cloud-utils debootstrap euca2ools libapparmor1 lxc python-boto python-m2crypto python-yaml`'...

Comment: @Parto OP was thinking that the lxc package had a lxc binary. But it's also cammand-not-found mistake to make OP think that there is a lxc command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting. I get the same:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lxc
...
$ lxc
The program 'lxc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install lxc
$
```

If you run:

```
$ dpkg-query -L lxc
```

you can see what files `lxc` has installed. There are a bunch in `/usr/bin` that start `lxc-`, like `/usr/bin/lxc-list` which do work, and some start up stuff in `/etc/init.d/`.

So, I reckon it is installed OK, you just need to find the name of the right executable.

Comment: What did you get after run `apt-get install`?

Comment: Too much to post here, but `apt-get` installed `lxc` and a whole bunch of dependencies

Comment: Yup, `dpkg-query` runs fine and lists a load of installed stuff. `lxc-ls` seems to run OK so I'm guessing I'm misunderstanding a broader problem. Thanks!

Comment: @snim2 Oh, so you hadn't it installed first. Thanks! Conclusion: a bug. *Note: you can upload big data in paste.ubuntu.com*

Comment: This smells like a bug... lxc does not actually install a binary named `lxc`, but other binaries for their own functions. But it should still be reported as installed, or the suggestion to install the package should be removed.

Comment: I'm not sure it is a bug. I think it is legitimate for a package to package things other than a single binary. A set of binaries or scripts called `lxc-*` makes `lxc` a perfectly reasonable package name.

Comment: You can use aliases or symbolic links there as *"solution"*.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem on Ubuntu 20.04 and figured out a solution from: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/950#issuecomment-127284021

TL;DR You need to install `lxd-client` package to get `lxc` command instead of lower level `lxc-*` commands.